# Que veut-dire “catalogne”?

Tags: vocabulaire

Et non, ce n’est pas le pays. Dans le livre « Le canard de bois » par Louis Caron, on utilise le mot « catalogne » comme le suivant:

> Il la souleva doucement entre ses mains et glissa la catalogne sous le corps inerte

Je n’ai absolument rien pu trouver de ce que veut dire ce mot.

Comment: Il y a à la fin du livre un « répertoire des quelques termes et quelques faits étrangers au public français » dans lequel ce québécisme,  et d'autres, sont expliqués.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On trouve l'explication à la page 17 du livre.

- Hyacinthe se pencha sur sa traîne, simple traîneau sans patins
  couché sur des lattes de frêne recourbées à l'avant. Une
  catalogne recouvrait son chargement. C'était une couverture à
  dominante mauve, confectionnée avec tous les bouts de tissu de
  cinq ans d'usage domestique.

On trouve une définition précise à la page 330.

- Catalogne : « Couverture de lit faite au métier par les Canadiennes, avec des
  retailles de coton ou toutes sortes de menus restes d'étoffe. » (Louis-A.
  Bélisle, Petit Dictionnaire canadien de la langue française, Éditions Aries,
  Montréal.)

Answer (score 9):

Dans une [autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/40005) on a établi qu'il s'agissait d'une *couverture* dans l’œuvre ; plus [généralement](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=CATALOGNE&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) la [*lirette*](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/lirette/47377?q=lirette#47308) ou *catalogne* (au Québec) c'est aussi le :

> Tissage artisanal dont la chaîne est le plus souvent en coton ou en
>   lin et la trame faite de fines bandes de tissu. (Au Québec, il est
>   appelé *catalogne*.) (Larousse en ligne, *lirette*)

Ou l'*étoffe* qui « peut servir à la fabrication de tissus, de tapis, de couvertures, etc. » ([GDT](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8358852)). Le mot *catalogne* était attesté en français classique (1635, voire [avant](https://www.erudit.org/fr/revues/haf/1961-v15-n3-haf2036/302137ar.pdf)) et il demeure en usage au Québec pour désigner l'étoffe et les couvertures, tapis que l'on confectionne avec (DHLF). L'article au [GPFC](http://bibnum2.banq.qc.ca/bna/numtxt/179630.pdf) résume bien le tout et mentionne aussi la présence du terme signifiant « couverture de lit » dans les anciens dialectes (Bourgogne, Auvergne, Normandie, Picardie, Savoie, Bretagne) ; j'ajoute un détail de la technique permettant de l'identifier aisément :

[image]
[image]

<sup><sup>Détails de catalognes (voir aussi [ici](http://collections.textilemuseum.ca/fr/search?criteria=catalogne) et [ici](http://canadiantapestry.ca/fr/det-T04_29_1.html) pour d'autres exemples) / Article « catalogne » au *Glossaire du parler français au Canada* (1930)</sup></sup>

Answer (score 3):

Pour ajouter aux autres réponses. *Car c'est une couverture faite à la mains, mais de caractéristique spéciale.*

Une catalogne peut être faite à la main avec des morceaux de restant de coton ou de laine, mais une catalogne à la base reste **lourde** et compacte. C’est une de ses caractéristiques principales.

Le tissu est tissé serré et/ou bien en plusieurs couches de retailles. L'originalité de la catalogne est qu'elle est très chaude et le fait qu'elle est lourde crée un effet recherché pour se sentir enveloppé en exemple. Due aux mauvaises isolations et chauffage au bois, dans le temps de mes grands-parents on la trouvait souvent dans les maisons d’époque au Canada Français. En temps normal, dans un lit, la catalogne est mise au dessus d'un autre drap de lit car la catalogne est chaude mais moins confortable qu'un drap ou une couverture normale.

Voici en exemple deux catalognes que j'ai chez moi;

[image]

[image]